# JS data becomes undefined after post. (node, socket.io, express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I just started coding a few days ago, so my terminology might be a little off, but here goes.

So I have an object `var users = {};` in my app.js file. In my client side code I have a function that takes the $nickBoxVal() from the input field and passes it as (data) on the client side and on the server side as (data).

So I have something like this on the client side:

```
$nickForm.submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
    socket.emit('new user', $nickBox.val(), function(data) {
      //stuff
    });
      $nickBox.val('');
});
```

and on the server:

```
socket.on('new user', function(data, callback) {
  if (data in users) {
    callback(false);
  } else {
    callback(true);
    socket.nickname = data;
    users[socket.nickname] = socket;
    updateNicknames();
  }
});

function updateNicknames() {
  io.sockets.emit('usernames', Object.keys(users)); 
}
```

Now when I go to the next page the (data) becomes undefined. I have done quite a bit of research and it seems that my code is asynchronous when it needs to be synchronous. All the guides I find tell me to declare the undefined var outside the function so that it is a global variable, but my (data) is not a var (as far as I know) and I didn't define it my self. (data) is the property of the user {} object.

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

"data" is a parameter to the callback function. It's only in scope inside that function. Other functions can't refer to it. "data" takes on different values when the callback function is called; referring to the parameter outside of the function is meaningless.